# What is the usage of $(TargetDir) in batch programming

Tags: batch-file

I am new with batch programming. My question is:

```
COPY /Y "$(TargetDir)*.xlsx"     "C:\Folder1"
```

I have the above written in a Visual Studio project (web app), if I click on properties - build events - in the "post build event command line" text area. How do I see **where** this variable is defined or is this a syst var? I am referring to **$(TargetDir)**.

I assume this command copies (suppressing prompting to confirm that you want to overwrite an existing destination file) all the xlsx files from a directory to C:\Folder1. I'd like to understand **how the destination directory is set**. Also, what is the explanation of exit with code 1 type of errors?

Can you suggest a **resource** with all the batch commands and var?

Comment: That variable is specific to a Visual Studio environment. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the one I learnt Batch with: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7wtLhgdLSa-Z2NMVGJVQzdFY1U/edit
Hope that helps you. Also, `COPY /Y "$(TargetDir)*.xlsx"     "C:\Folder1"` is not batch syntax, although similar.
the batch equivalent is:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%I in (*.xlsx) do (
copy %%I C:\Folder1
)
```

save as rename.bat

Hope that helped!